# Open-Uri timeout on pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, open-uri

I am currently generating a temporary pdf file from an associated url to store inside of my rails app's tmp folder. I will then use the filepath as a parameter of an api call to a third party application. Here is my method for attempting to create the file:

```
def get_temporary_pdf(chrono_detail, recording, host)
    auth_token = User.find(chrono_detail.user_id).authentication_token
    pdf_location = host + '/recordings/' + recording.id.to_s + '/analysis.pdf/?format=pdf&download=true&token=' + auth_token
    filename = "Will" + '_' + recording.id.to_s + '_' + Date.new.to_s + '.pdf'
    File.open(Rails.root.join("tmp",filename), "wb") do |file|
      file.write open(pdf_location, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}).read
    end
    Rails.root.join("tmp",filename)
    return "/Users/williamsumfest/Desktop/Ekodevices/eko_web/tmp/" + filename
  end
```

When the program is run and this method is referenced, I receive the error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout - Net::ReadTimeout:
```

which originates from the line in the code that uses open(). I've seen similar problems with open-uri, but my pdf's are fairly small. Also, I am using thin so the requests should be able to be processed at the same time. Does anyone have any advise?